# How could one write a generic sorting function in C++?

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list, generic-programming

Is there any possible method to sort all kind of data in natural sense with a single function in C++? In my case I define a linked list structures that based on a template datatype and I would like to sort that linked list whatever it includes as a data.

Comment: Ahem [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) ?

Comment: @Borgleader - the poster says he's got a linked list, which won't work with `std::sort` as it's highly unlikely to be a random access structure.

Comment: @Sean You missed the point. The question is "Is it possible". Yes look at std::sort.

Comment: Take a look at [std::list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) and its [std::list::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/) function.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple dimensions to what you could mean by generic:

1. generic with respect to the data
2. generic with respect to the container

The first is the easiest to tackle. We need to think about what sorting requires to work: a [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) of our data. Now we know the nature of the function we need to supply to our sorting algorithm and need a way to pass the function. In C++ it has become the norm to assume `operator<` implements such an order or to pass a Functor to the algorithm that implements it. So the signature would become:

```
template<typename T, typename Comp = std::less<T>>
my_sort(my_list<T>& l, Comp c = Comp());
```

There is another operation our sorting algorithm will necessarily perform: swapping elements. As we are in our own little world here we can just assume that all our types have a member function `T::swap(T& rhs)` which does exactly this. In the real world we would use the free function `std::swap` (with an unqualified call and a using directive, but that is an obscure technicality).

The second problem is far trickier and you actually don't want to tackle it, as you only want your sort algorithm to work on your list implementation. I encourage you to dive into [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and its requirement to understand why it has been implemented this way and why it does not work for `std::list`.

Comment: Note that for a list, it may be better to fix internal list pointer without swapping data (which may be not swappable).

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is, you can implement insertion sort quite naturally with a linked list. You can write a templated function with similar interface as [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

You can then use `operator<` for comparing any kind of elements or the `Compare` function.

You can allow your list as an input, and return a sorted list as an output.

The complexity will drop to `O(n^2)` with insertion sort, but that is the easiest way IMO. <del>And I don't think you can do better with out random access container.</del> Maybe merge sort could be implemented for list. Seems like a good candidate.

Alternatively you could copy/move your list into a structure that supports random access iterators sort it with `std::sort` and transform it back into a list. That would technically have better complexity, but quite big constant factors due to 2 transform operations. But for big lists it would be faster in the end.

Comment: You really should not care about copies or moves, but `swap`. This is also what `std::sort` does.

Comment: When you compute pure computational complexity, yes of course. When you use a data structure to sort small sets (I know you can say I should not care about small data sets 'cause they are fast by definition), it's worth to remember that copying stuff around takes time too. And `swap` is a copy or a move anyways, ain't it? Also I think in a poorly designed algorithm (kind of like mine rough sketch here) you will be bound by memory and the number of swaps can become less dominant operation. I saw few examples that assumed `malloc` is nice O(1) operation and broke their complexity.

Comment: I was not trying to say copies or moves are irrelevant for performance, but that swap generalizes copy construction/move construction. If you have a good definition (in the mathematical sense) of `swap` your lower level algorithms don't need to care about the underlying mechanism.

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought you were saying that copying contents, or any conversion between containers is irrelevant because from the algorithmic point of view you should count only swaps. Of course you're right, but to me it is essentially the same, like you pointed out, just different nomenclature. Sorry if I made an unclear shortcut. I sometimes like to use explicit operation names because I consider `copy` to be just an upper bound for `move`. (Side note: Just to be clear and precise in comparison-sorting algorithms the complexity is defined by number of comparisons).